# Riot.js event handler gives Uncaught TypeError and DOM does not update correctly

Tags: jquery, event-handling, materialize, typeerror, riot.js

I'm working on a project that uses Riot.js, Materialize.css, and jQuery (mainly because of Materialize components). When I try to make an event handler using Riot.js for any element, I get an Uncaught TypeError when fired and the DOM doesn't update correctly afterwards. I have tried many ways to get around the error but nothing has solved the issue. My best guess at what the problem is is that somehow Riot.js and jQuery (along with Materialize?) are messing with the DOM at the same time which causes sync issues. This has been bugging me for quite a while now and has impeded progress on the site so any help is greatly appreciated!

Riot.js version: 2.5.0

Materialize.css version: 0.97.7

jQuery version (provided by Materialize.css): 2.1.4

Here is the stack trace output by Chrome's console:

```
jquery.js:4769 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of undefined
    handlers             @ jquery.js:4769
    dispatch             @ jquery.js:4718
    elemData.handle      @ jquery.js:4549
    trigger              @ jquery.js:7807
    (anonymous function) @ jquery.js:7875
    each                 @ jquery.js:365
    each                 @ jquery.js:137
    trigger              @ jquery.js:7874
    (anonymous function) @ materialize.js:3191
    dispatch             @ jquery.js:4737
    elemData.handle      @ jquery.js:4549
```

Here is my *index.html* (stripped down to relevant info):

```
<!doctype html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/materialize/css/materialize.min.css">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="section">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col s12 m6">
            <recruiting-form></recruiting-form>
          </div> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="/riot/riot+compiler.min.js"></script>
    <script type="riot/tag" src="recruiting-form.tag"></script>

    <script src="/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/materialize/js/materialize.js"></script>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        riot.mount('*');
      });
    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Here is my *recruiting-form.tag* (stripped down to relevant info):

```
<recruiting-form>

  <div class="row">
    <form class="col s12>
      <div class="row">

        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <select onchange={ checkPlatform }>
            <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your platform</option>
            <option value="PC">PC</option>
            <option value="PS4">PlayStation 4</option>
            <option value="XB1">Xbox One</option>
          </select>
          <label>Platform</label>
        </div>

        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <select disabled={ regionDisabled }>
            <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your region</option>
            <option value="US">Americas</option>
            <option value="EU">Europe</option>
            <option value="KR">Asia</option>
          </select>
          <label>Region</label>
        </div>

      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

  <script>
    this.regionDisabled = true;

    checkPlatform(e) {
      if (e.currentTarget.value === 'PC') {
        this.regionDisabled = false;
      } else {
        this.regionDisabled = true;
      }
    }

    this.on('mount', function() {
      $('select').material_select();
    });
  </script>

</recruiting-form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
checkPlatform(e) {
  if (e.currentTarget.value === 'PC') {
    this.regionDisabled = false;
  } else {
    this.regionDisabled = true;
  }
}
```

What is this referring to? Looks like it's trying to process an event or something, but it's not in a function.

It looks like it's trying to modify the DOM but it's not yet initialized. You should move this section into the `on('mount')` or call it from within the `on('mount')`

Comment: It's an event handler and that's how Riot.js said to write them. The problem with putting that event handler into the `on('mount')` is that I can't get the event to find `checkPlatform`. It's the same reason why I have `this.regionDisabled = true;` outside of the `on('mount')`. I put alerts inside of the `checkPlatform` event handler for testing and I didn't get anything.

Comment: Oh sorry, that is indeed standard riotjs form.
I think I ran into some issues so I use the "normal" `this.myFunction=function..` to produce a locally scoped function.

Answer (score 0):

You have a missing " in col s12, change it to

```
  <div class="row">
    <form class="col s12">
      <div class="row">
```

Also add  this code to apply the material after update

```
this.on('update', function() {
  $('select').material_select();
});
```

Here is the working fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/vitomd/Lm4dy21d/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

Complete code:

```
checkPlatform(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  if (e.currentTarget.value === 'PC') {
    this.regionDisabled = false;
  } else {
    this.regionDisabled = true;
  }
}
```